# How to use grape entity based on value of a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-grape, grape-entity

Anyone worked on Grape & Grape entity i have an issue.
db: Mongoid
I have two models 
1. User
2. Answers

every user have package_type: `1` or `2` or `3`
and every answer also have package type in array but of single value.
LIKE `[1]` or `[2]` or `[3]`.

I want to send those answer in response which have package_type == users.package_type.

user_entity:

```
expose :answers, as: :profile_info, using: API::V1::Entities::Answer
```

answer_entity:

```
module API
    module V1
        module Entities
            class Answer < Grape::Entity
                expose :answer
                expose :question
                expose :package_type
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that filtering from the relation

```
class User
  has_many :answers, -> { where({answers: {package_type: self.package_type}}) }
end
```

or from the entity

```
expose :profile_info do |user, _options| 
  API::V1::Entities::Answer.represent(user.answers.where({answers: {package_type: user.package_type}}))
end
```